# Ruby: Cannot Install Watir Gem On Windows

Tags: ruby, watir

[Watir's site](http://watir.com/installation/) says I need Ruby 1.8.6, which I'm running. And windows installation should be as simple as `gem install watir`. But when I run that, I get this:

```
C:\Users\Ryguy\Code>gem install watir
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing watir:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

C:/Ruby/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for strncpy_s()... no
creating Makefile

make
'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/win32-api-1.4.5 f
Results logged to C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/win32-api-1.4.5/ext/gem_make.out
```

**My Ruby Version:** ruby 1.8.6 (2009-08-04 patchlevel 383) [i386-mingw32]
**My RubyGems Version:** 1.3.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend you install the RubyInstaller Development Kit as documented [here](http://wiki.github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/development-kit)

Once you've installed it, the compile process of Watir dependencies (win32-api) will install successfully.

Comment: Yes, this is what I did =) Thanks though

Comment: Don't want to put your statement on doubt, but are you sure? I've managed to compile most of the Windows gems with the DevKit without issues, including win32utils ones.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed to install the Ruby Development files. =/

Comment: Just a thought...Our company started out in Windows and quickly found that it'd be easier to use Cygwin (a linux 'emulator'), then we switched to virtualized Ubuntu because it was a bit of a pain to try and run Ruby on Windows. Good Luck though!

Answer (score 0):

Execute Below command and its works

gem install watir --platform=mswin32

Answer (score 0):

Installed devkit and after calling the bat file on Windows 7 from a cmd it fixed this issue. Using Ruby 1.9.1

Comment: "the bat file"... which bat file? very unhelpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

I also had to install nokogiri to get Watir to install successfully on windows, after installing DevKit.  Use: gem install nokogiri